# Error in creating repository in azure using azure cloud plugin?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

I created storage account in azure but when i create a repository in azure it is showing error like this.

I given command as
 PUT _snapshot/azurerepository
{
  "type": "azure"
}

Response

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason": "[azurerepository] can not initialize container elasticsearch-snapshots"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_verification_exception",
    "reason": "[azurerepository] can not initialize container elasticsearch-snapshots",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "storage_exception",
      "reason": "An unknown failure occurred : Connection refused: connect",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "connect_exception",
        "reason": "Connection refused: connect"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to my network connection under some firewall. Once firewall is removed i can to access azure with out any problem.